# Create a linked server in SQL Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We have using two databases that is used for cross database queries.One is named azureDB1 and another is azureDB2.These databases resides on my Azure cloud SQL Server.Our scenario is to call a stored procedure that resides in azureDB2 from azureDB1.For this  we have tried to create a linked server using "sp_addlinkedserver" stored procedure.But we got error message that "Could not find stored procedure 'SP_ADDLINKEDSERVER'". We need solution for create linked server in sql azure server

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.  This is asking about creating a linked server "from" Azure.  The other is asking about creating a linked server "to" Azure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Linked server for Azure SQL Database is not supported. However you can use 
Elastic Query which allows you to query across SQL Databases
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-overview/

Comment: Specifically, take a look at the sp_execute_remote stored procedure. It allows you to invoke a stored proc in a remote database in SQLDB.